# Creating a logfile via windows desktop shortcut using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, shortcut, logfile

Good evening, this might be a super short question.

I created a well working PowerShell Script... now I want to create a desktop shortcut which automatically runs this script and creates a logfile.

**My attempt was to create a shortcut with this as destination argument:**

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& {C:\Users\name\Desktop\final.ps1}" > C:\Users\name\Desktop\report.log`

It does run the script and also creates a file but it is empty. If I run the same line on the PowerShell Console itself, it runs perfectly fine... :(

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it will work, but you could try putting the redirect part inside your command like this

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& {& C:\Users\name\Desktop\final.ps1 > C:\Users\name\Desktop\report.log}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use (with line breaks for clarity):

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
-Command "& 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\final.ps1' | Out-File 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\report.log'"
```

However, if you continue to have problems, then I'd create a batch file with that as contents, and point the shortcut to the batch file.